# Using a list in batch file

Tags: windows, batch

I need to copy a file if exist to a list of destinations. The Destination contain `%variables%` . When I run it appears to be using the `%appdata%` as stated in the array list instead of the `c:\Users\NAME\Appdata\roaming\`

How can I make it use the variable in the array list?

The `.lnk` and the `Shortcut_Locations.txt` are located in same folder as script.

```
@echo off

pushd "%~dp0" 

set source_file=App1.lnk

set destination_list=Shortcut_Locations.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%I in (%destination_list%) do (
    if exist "%%I" (
        copy /Y "%source_file%" "%%I"
    )
)

POPD
```

`Shortcut_Locations.txt` content:

```
\\\server1\data\\%username%\Desktop\\
%appdata%\OpenShell\Pinned\\
%appdata%\OpenShell\Pinned\GGHC\\
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just modifying the FOR. This worked instead of using a list. Still unsure why a %appdata% inside a list didn't work.

```
for %%I in (\\Server1\data\%username%\Desktop,
%appdata%\OpenShell\Pinned,
%appdata%\OpenShell\Pinned\GGHC)
```